# Trinidad tr:treeTable expand/collapse commands

Tags: jsf-2, tree, myfaces, trinidad

I am using Trinidad 2.0. My problem is expand/collapse commands of treeTable. I think they
are supposed to automatically expand/collapse tree nodes, but
by clicking them, nothing happens and I got the exception

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/MyXhtml.xhtml]
01/05/2012 15:31:08 org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.core.xhtml.PanelPartialRootRenderer encodeAll   
SEVERE: Error displaying partial page   
java.lang.NullPointerException   
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.getFacesBean(CoreRenderer.java:739)   
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.core.desktop.TreeTableRenderer.renderSpecialColumns(TreeTableRenderer.java:379)   
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.core.desktop.DesktopTableRenderer.renderSingleRow(DesktopTableRenderer.java:113)   
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.core.xhtml.TableRenderer.encodeAll(TableRenderer.java:388)   
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.core.desktop.TreeTableRenderer.encodeAll(TreeTableRenderer.java:177)
```

and I see this exception in FireBug:

> ```
> _logError(varArgs="Invalid PPR response. T...ror></partial-response>")
> ```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

We are doing migration from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0. In JSF 1.2 the `<tr:treeTable>` works fine, but now with JSF 2.0 and trinidad 2.0 I have these errors when I try to expand or collapse nodes. By the way, component `<tr:tree>` from trinidad 2.0 works just fine, but we need `<tr:treeTable>`.

The JARs used by the webapplication are:

- commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
- commons-codec-1.3.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.jar
- commons-digester-1.8.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- myfaces-bundle-2.1.7.jar
- myfaces-impl-2.1.7.jar
- trinidad-api-2.0.0.jar
- trinidad-impl-2.0.0.jar

I am using MyEclipse 10 as IDE.

Comment: Don't you have a concrete exception and stacktrace? That "Error Rendering View" message basically means that *an* exception has occurred which is usually logged right after that line. You should copypaste that instead.

Comment: Sorry,that I don't write my exception,

Comment: Just edit your question and include it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Trinidad 2.0.0 source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.myfaces.trinidad/trinidad-api/2.0.0/org/apache/myfaces/trinidad/render/CoreRenderer.java/#739), this is what is happening around line 739 of `CoreRenderer#getFacesBean()`:

```
736   protected FacesBean getFacesBean(
737     UIComponent component)
738   {
739     return ((UIXComponent) component).getFacesBean();
740   }
```

So, `component` is `null`.

You probably don't want to hear this, but this is really a bug in Trinidad as it's only been used by Trinidad internal code. I'd start upgrading to the [latest](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/download.html) Trinidad 2.x version (which is currently 2.0.1). It might already be fixed in there. If not, then [report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TRINIDAD) it as a new bug to the Trinidad guys.

Comment: Hi,I opened the jira three days ago, here is the link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TRINIDAD-2265 , but how much time they need to fix the bug like this?and if it will be fixed in trinidad 2.0.2?Do you know something about this from your expirience?Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Trinidad, nor do I track their activity.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with expand/collapse command of treeTable when I have changed my IDE.
from MyEclipse 10 to SpringSource Tool Suite 2.9.1,In this IDE all expand/collapse commands of treeTable work just fine.